# Loop to check if one and only one element in an array is different to all the rest

Tags: loops, iteration

Say I have an array of `Ball` objects, where each ball is red, blue or green and `Ball.getColour()` returns the colour of the ball. I want to check that all, but one, balls in the array are the same colour. How can I do this in one pass of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would build another structure counting balls by color.

```
var countArray = [0, 0, 0]  // the count of red, blue and green
for each ball in ballArray {
    index = ball.mapColorToIndex() // (red->0, green->1, blue->2) 
    countArray[index]++
}
countArray = countArray.sortAscending()
// array must now be of the form 0, 1, n where n is ballArray.count()-1
if (countArray[0]==0 && countArray[1]==1 && countArray[2]>1) {
   // OP condition met
}
```

This generalizes for more colors, but it might be better to sort descending and check the end of the array for ..0,0,1,n.

Also, as number of colors grows, you end up with another array traversal for the sort. (with only 3 colors, we can write an O(1) sort).  This can be avoided by keeping pointers to the conditions you care about (index with a singular count, and index with a >1 count) in the first loop.